# iTunes fails to sync with iPod Touch, suggests I should reset it to factory defaults

Tags: itunes, windows, ipod-touch

I'm unable to perform a backup from my iPod Touch to iTunes because it says it's failing to read data from it and that I have to reset it to factory defaults. This will erase all data on the device.

I have, however, over 2000 songs on it that I don't want to lose, and thousands of contacts that I'd rather not lose as well. I tried to backup them with PodTrans but it gives me the same bad news that the device's database is corrupted.

From the device's side though, all is well and it's working normally.

The device was working fine with iTunes until it was halfway through a backup and now it won't sync again.

I've tried several different cables with no success, it doesn't seem to be a cable issue.

I've tried rebooting and restarting iTunes background processes several times with no success.

Is there anything else I can try to save my data from this device?

Comment: You could try another computer, just in case, but for direct backup/sync to a computer rather than iCloud, the computer is 'in charge' & the iDevice merely a slave. It won't, even under normal circumstances, backup tunes that are not already on the computer [other than any sync with 'iTunes Music' which works differently, but i don't use & have no experience with]

Answer (score 2):

Can you tell us what version of iOS you're running? Unless it's really old, you can sync contacts to your iCloud account, and if you go to iCloud.com and log in with your Apple ID you'd see them. You can also do an iCloud backup. Regarding songs, how did you get them on your iPod initially? If they were already on your computer then you should be able to put them back again after the restore. If you purchased them through iTunes you should be able to re-download them for free.